# 389 ldap user and group migration RHEL7

Tags: redhat, ldap

I want to know how to migrate user's and the group's on 389 LDAP directory server on RHEL 7 using the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Not required but you may want to make the directory server read-only for the duration to get a consistent state:

```
ldapmodify -D "cn=directory manager" -W -p 389 -h server.example.com -x
```

Change the read-only attribute to on

```
dn: cn=database_name,cn=ldbm database,cn=plugins,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: nsslapd-readonly
nsslapd-readonly: on
```

And then use the [`db2ldif`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/db2ldif/) utility to export specific parts of your directory tree i.e.:

```
db2ldif -s 'OU=Users,dc=example,dc=com' -a ./users.example.com.ldif -m -E -q
db2ldif -s 'OU=Groups,dc=example,dc=com' -a ./groups.example.com.ldif -m -E -q
```